# Spring 4.2.4 - Autowire stopped working in RAD WAS 8.5 once Java 8 was installed

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

The application was running fine in WAS 8.5 for several years, including local WAS8.5 server in RAD. Installed Java 8 on laptop, recompiled code in RAD under JDK 1.7 (only on installed), restarted server and got below error on start up:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
> Error creating bean with name 'addressController': Injection of
> autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
> autowire field: private
> com.components.mds.service.StaticReferenceService
> com.mds.ui.controller.MDSBaseController.staticRefService;
> nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type
> [com.components.mds.service.StaticReferenceService] found
> for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
> candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
> {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)

The application has ear with presentation (jsps, controllers, etc) and jar with services, DAO, etc. The jar is included in the lib folder of the ear. In the ear (war), the controller has following code:

```
@Controller
```

@SessionAttributes({MDS_PRESCRIBER_ADDRESS_MAP , MDS_PRESCRIBER})
public class AddressController extends MDSBaseController {

```
private String editAddressID;
private AddressModel addressPhoneModel = new AddressModel();
@Autowired
AddressValidations addressValidator;
```

and has spring-context.xml with following:

```
<context:spring-configured />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.caremark.mds.ui.customtag"></context:component-scan>
    <context:load-time-weaver aspectj-weaving="on" />
```

The above will try to autowire class in jar:

```
@Component
```

public class AddressValidator {

```
public boolean validatePrescriberAddress(Address address){
```

...
}

with spring-component-context.xml that specifies beans:

```
<!-- Bean defined in JAR -->
    <context:component-scan base-package=" com.components.mds.service" />
    <context:component-scan base-package=" com.components.mds.business" />
    <context:component-scan base-package=" com.components.mds.validation" />
    <context:component-scan base-package=" com.components.mds.dao" />
    <context:component-scan base-package=" com.components.mds.auth.service" />
    <context:component-scan base-package=" com.components.mds.auth.dao" />
    <context:component-scan base-package=" com.components.mds.audit.service" />
    <context:component-scan base-package=" com.components.mds.audit.dao" />
    <context:component-scan base-package=" com.components.mds.audit.vo" />
    <!--  DO not declare beans here just use annotations in class file -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
```

The Static Reference class is also annotated:

```
@Service
```

public class StaticReferenceServiceImpl implements StaticReferenceService {
//SLF4J Log handler
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StaticReferenceServiceImpl.class);

```
@Autowired
private StaticReferenceDao staticRefDao;

@Autowired
private MDSEhCacheManager<StaticReference,Map<String,ReferenceDataVO>> cacheManager;
```

It looks like class from the war cannot see the class in the jar that is in the lib folder of the war under WEB-INF\lib

Any suggestions why it would stop working if the only change is laptop upgrade to use Java 8

Answer (score 0):

The error log is showing that it is not able to inject `private com.components.mds.service.StaticReferenceService` defined in `com.mds.ui.controller.MDSBaseController.staticRefService` you should check `StaticReferenceService` whether it is annotated with any of the Spring annotation like `component, service`

Comment: Yes - see my updated code snippet. And also it was working until Java 8 was installed and application was recompiled in old JDK1.7 in RAD